# Usar routerLinkActive sin usar routerLink

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ngroute

Buenas a todos. Os cuento mi problema.

He tenido que modificar mi HTML para quitar el `routerLink=""` y hacer ahora esa lógica en el controlador con `router.navigate[()]`

De forma que el html es algo así:

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" (click)="changeUrl('0')">
          <a>
             <span>{{menu[0].title}}</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" (click)="changeUrl('1')">
          <a>
             <span>{{menu[1].title}}</span>
          </a>
     </li>
```

Y en el component.ts simplemente se controla en el metodo `changeUrl(orden: number)` que muestre al usuario un mensaje de confirmación antes de hacer el
 `router.navigate[()]` para redirigirle en caso de que acepte.

El problema es que con estos cambios el `routerLink="active"` ha dejado de funcionar.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me autocontesto.

La solución que he encontrado al final pasa por eliminar directamente el routerLinkActive y setear la clase "active" con un [class.active]="menu[0].active"

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li [class.active]="menu[0].active" (click)="changeUrl('0')">
          <a>
             <span>{{menu[0].title}}</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li [class.active]="menu[0].active"  (click)="changeUrl('1')">
          <a>
             <span>{{menu[1].title}}</span>
          </a>
     </li>
```

Como la  lista menú es una lista de RouteInfo he añadido el valor active desde el componente con la instruccion:

```
menuItem['active'] = true;
```